# Replaced fragment visible behind the "new" fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmenttransaction, fragmentmanager

I use a mainActivity which contains a frameLayout.
In this framelayout i load different fragments (by clicking on a menuitem in a navigation drawer) When i switch between fragments with a static layout (.xml layout file) everything works fine. 1 fragment has a dynamic created layout (which is created in the `onCreateView` method). When i navigate to this fragment and navigate back to another fragment i can still see the "old" fragment with the dynamic created controls trough the "new" fragment.

The code what i use to switch between the fragment is:

```
mFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
mFragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
mFragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fr_content_container,new AlertOverviewFragment()).commit();



mNavigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();

        if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.nav_item_alerts) {
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fr_content_container, new AlertOverviewFragment()).commit();
        }

        if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.nav_item_news) {
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fr_content_container, new NewsFragment()).commit();
        }

        if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.nav_item_add_country) {
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fr_content_container, new AddCountryFragment()).commit();

        }
        return false;
    }

});
```

I can give the background of the new activity a background color so the old fragment isn't visible anymore but i think this is not the best practice solution. The old fragment will then still exist. **What is the best way to solve this problem?**

AND when i have this problem with this fragmen, are there then also other fragments that still exist in the background after navigate to another fragment? **when yes, do i need to "destroy" these before switch to the new fragment or something?**

I read something about the live cycles and understand this but i thought Android manages these states by him self?